# verification of user id '<null>' not configured for anonymous user

Tags: apache, authentication, null, httpd.conf, verification

Hi I am using Centos 5 and Apache/2.2.15 .
When I try to access a file from a different machine , I get below error :

access to /mydir/myfile.php failed, reason: verification of user id '' not configured

There are several similar problems on this , But as I am not using authentication for connection , those solutions are not working for me .
Below you can find the related conf file :

```
Listen 13001
Alias /infoser "/usr/share/www/mydir/"
<Directory "/usr/share/www/mydir/">
    Anonymous_NoUserID on
    AuthzUserAuthoritative on
    Options Indexes
    AuthType None
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have also tried without "AuthzUserAuthoritative on" but it did not work also.
Interestingly I try with similar configuration with a httpd server running on Fedora 19 (version is Apache/2.4.10)

```
Listen 13001
Alias /infoser "/usr/share/www/mydir/"
<Directory "/usr/share/www/mydir/">
    Options Indexes
    AuthType None
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and this is working while connecting from a different machine.

Could you please inform me what could be the reason?

NOTE : I can say that httpd.conf is same on Centos and Fedora 19

Comment: when I disabled "Require all granted" with # character I see that it is working.
But this directive is explained as "Access is allowed unconditionally."
I did not understand why it is blocking.

Comment: I have found the problem. The reason is because of the version difference. In 2.2 "Require all granted" is not being used . When I removed this line, error has gone